# How to save 4 drop down list selections to a cookie, and set drops if cookie present

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am using jQuery and have setup the jquery cookie plugin.

I have 4 drop down lists on my page, and I want to save the user's selections in a cookie, so when they come back to the page I automatically pre-select their previous selections.

I added a class to all my drop downs "ddl-cookie", and I was just thinking if I could somehow loop through all the drop down lists using the class, and save the selection and also loop to set the selections when the user returns to the page.

```
$(".ddl-cookie").each(function() {

});
```

It seems that given a cookie name, I can save a single key/value in the cookie.

So I'm guessing the only way for me to do this would be to have a comma separated list of drop down list names and values (selection value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  Cookies are intended to store a single piece of data, so the most common way to handle this is to serialize your data into an easy to retrieve format.  That format is up to you, but you might use something like:

```
field_1=value1&field_2=value&...
```

You might want to also encode this data--remember that cookies are transferred as part of the request header.  The pseudo code would go something like this:

```
// Store the data, using your own defined methods
data = serialize_data(data);
data = encode_data(data);
cookie = data;

// Retrieve the data using your own defined methods
data = cookie;
data = unencode_data(data)
data = deserialize_data(data)
```

Comment: why do I have to encode it? you mean if I don't some characters might be lost?

Comment: Correct--your browser normally encodes data when a form is submitted so that only allowed characters are sent in the HTTP request.  When setting a cookie, you'll need to do this manually.  It's not necessarily required, but definitely good practice and may cause problems if you don't.  I've also amended my answer to use a serialized format like query strings.  It's a standard format, and I believe jQuery provides methods for coercing data into and out of query string format.